# Inferior limit when t decreases to 0

Tags: limits, definition, limsup-and-liminf

I just found in a book, the notation (for a real valued function $f$)
$$ \liminf_{t \searrow 0} f(t)$$
I know what $$\liminf_{t\to 0} f(t)$$ means: 
$$\liminf_{t\to 0} f(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\inf_{s\in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]} f(s)\right)$$ but how can I define
$$ \liminf_{t \searrow 0} f(t) ?$$
Is it equivalent to
 $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0,\epsilon >0} \left(\inf_{s\in [0,\epsilon]} f(s)\right)?$$

Comment: I would bet that your guess is right.

Comment: Shouldn't the $\inf$'s be over $s\in [-\epsilon, \epsilon]\setminus\{0\}$ and $s\in (0, \epsilon]$ instead? When taking limits to $0$, the point $0$ itself is excluded. It seems reasonable to me that the same should go for $\liminf$.